# Does Couchbase Server have a binary JSON storage format?

Tags: couchbase

MongoDB has BSON, ArangoDB has VelocyPack, Postgresql has Jsonb,...

Does Couchbase also have its own binary format to work with JSON documents?

Comment: there are a couple storage engine options, depending on which version you're using: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/storage-engines.html - but I'm curious to know more about why you need this information?

Comment: Yes.  It does...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike What binary JSON format does Couchbase support?

Comment: @MatthewGroves why are you so curious about that?

Comment: Just wondering what use case or project you're working on where it matters. If you're using an SDK or connector, you don't really need to know. So, I suspect you're doing something unusual (possibly something cool and novel), and that interests me

Comment: I didn't say it supported any binary JSON format.  I said it used its own binary format to work with JSON documents.  The specifics of that format are absolutely not part of the Couchbase API.

Comment: @MatthewGroves I'm working on a research project comparing several document-oriented databases. Given the time and thought that went into developing VelocyPack or Jsonb, I'd say the binary format always matters when it comes to the performance of a database dealing with JSON.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But keep in mind there are many other factors when it comes to performance: indexing, querying, data modeling, use of caching, etc. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Couchbase Server uses a binary JSON storage format internally (I work at Couchbase but not on the server team, so I don't know), but from a user's perspective, as of Couchbase 7.1 in the year 2022, with the server-side SDKs, the answer is no.

You can store any kind of binary data in Couchbase (CBOR, Avro, protobuf, jpeg, etc.) but the server treats anything that isn't JSON as a blob. You cannot query the contents of a blob with N1QL or Full-Text Search, and you cannot perform subdocument operations on it.

The good news is that it typically doesn't matter. Instead of a user-facing binary JSON format, [Couchbase uses transparent Snappy compression](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/compression.html). As a user, you can work with ordinary JSON and let Couchbase handle the details of sending/storing it efficiently.

Comment: thanks for you answer. would you mind asking one of your colleagues working on the server team to confirm this information?

Comment: I am actually more interested in the format the storage engine uses internally than the user-facing format.

Comment: @3bst0r In that case, the link Matthew Groves shared about storage engines is indeed a great resource. I'd prefer not to be a go-between, but you can certainly ask the server team yourself! Best way to get in touch is to post in the [Couchbase Server category on the Couchbase Forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/couchbase-server/15).

Comment: Thanks, I posted a question there. https://forums.couchbase.com/t/binary-json-format-on-disk-or-in-memory/34436